# From time difference array to frequency (hz) - Java/Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, algorithm

I am developing an android app which detect the hand tremor (with accelerometer) and visualize this data in a graph with amplitude and frequency.

I am able to count time difference with:

```
timeArray[recCount] = time - startTime;
```

recCount is the variable of the total point measured by accelerometer.

I get the hand tremor with:

```
recArray[recCount] = accelZ;
```

with accelZ that represents the z-axis acceleration of the accelerometer.

Now i would like to plot a graph which contains:

- x-axis: frequency (hz) calculated from the timeArray.
- y-axis: the intensity of the tremor.

Could anyone help me how to get frequency array from time difference array?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Do you want the frequency of the amount of points measured by the accelerometer or the frequency of the actual movement (assuming it's periodical enough to define such a measure/quantity)?

Comment: Imagine in the y-axis the tremor intensity (as amplitude), and in the x-axis the frequency. I want the frequency of the actual movement

Comment: You are mixing a lot of terms together I'm afraid. But based on your answer (you want the frequency of the movement): you need to know what it is in the movement that you want to measure the frequency of. Do you approximate the movement using a sinus wave for example, and want this wave's frequency? Do you just want the frequency of points in time when the hand changes its direction?

Comment: Sorry for confusion :-) .
I would like to approximate the movement using a sinus wave where in x-axis there is the Hz of a hand tremor where its amplitude is represented in y-axis. Does it make more sense?
Otherwise if this not makes senseI would like to get the frequency of points in time when the hand changes its direction?

Comment: Kind of. But in this question, if I understand you, we specifically consider the problem of getting the frequency - meaning you need to approximate the movement using a sinus and get its frequency. It doesn't matter what you want to do with this frequency later on (in your case plot it as one coordinate of a 2D point in a graph). That has nothing to do with this question and it is only confusing. Unless I misunderstood something. Did I?

Comment: I am sorry I missed the point.
Do you mean to get the sinus final frequency or you are saying that it is possible to plot the frequency of each point in a graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122921/discussion-between-et-l-and-paride-letizia).